# How do I create a second nav bar drop down menu> Mine is staying connected with the first one i made

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am using HTML and CSS to create a website, and im currently working on a navigation bar at the top but I dont know how to seperate different nav bar buttons/create them. As when i tried to make a second one, when i hover over our athletes it also hovers over about us. How do I create different drop down buttons on one nav bar?

```css
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #BBBCC0;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rtsnp_home.css">
  <title>Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <!--no drop down-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">About Us
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Mission Statement</a>
        <a href="#">Our Founder</a>
        <a href="#">Our Board of Directors</a>
        <a href="#">National Board of Directors</a>
        <a href="#">Programs Offered</a>

      </div>
      <button class="dropbtn">Our Athletes
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"> Link 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi can you add css file as well?

Comment: I updated it, sorry thought it was just in my html that was causing the bug

Comment: great. I have added the answer

Comment: I went through your profile, since you are new to stackoverflow, you need to accept other's effort on putting answers if it solves your questions by putting a tick. When you tick other person's answer, it will grow your reputation as well. This is not a race

Answer (score 0):

It's a small mistake in the div tags. Here you go.
You need to seperate div tags from each dropdown, otherwise both will call at the same time which occurs in your snippet.

```css
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #BBBCC0;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rtsnp_home.css">
  <title>Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <!--no drop down-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">About Us
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Mission Statement</a>
        <a href="#">Our Founder</a>
        <a href="#">Our Board of Directors</a>
        <a href="#">National Board of Directors</a>
        <a href="#">Programs Offered</a>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Our Athletes
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"> Link 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, appreciate if you could put a tick and upvote.